# Parametrizing and Sampling Multivariate Garch Parameters Metropolis-Hastings MCMC

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, garch, multivariate-normal-distribution, metropolis-hastings

My question is how to sample multivariate GARCH parameters from a proposal distribution (multivariate normal) for a Metropolis-Hastings algorithm. Considering the different dimensions of the parameter list, and the assumed need for joint sampling, I am unsure how to handle the sampling.

I want to conduct a Metropolis-Hastings algorithm to optimize a set of multivariate garch (MGARCH) parameters. Let's assume for now that we have 2 dimensions.
The MGARCH Process is defined by:

$H_t = \Gamma_0 + \Gamma_1 \odot(y_{t-1})(y_{t-1})' + \Gamma_2\odot H_{t-1}$

$\odot$ denotes the Hadamard product (element-wise multiplication).

The set of MGARCH parameters is defined by $\Gamma = (\Gamma_0^{1/2},\gamma_1,\gamma_2)$ where $\Gamma_0 = \Gamma_0^{1/2}(\Gamma_0^{1/2})', \Gamma_1 = \gamma_1(\gamma_1)' $ and $ \Gamma_2 = \gamma_2(\gamma_2)'$. $\Gamma_0^{1/2}$ is a lower 2x2 triangular matrix, and $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are 2x1 vectors.

The proposal $\Gamma'$ is sampled from a multivariate normal distribution $N\sim(\Gamma,\hat{V})$. Where $\hat{V}$ is the inverse hessian matrix of the log posterior of the MGARCH parameters, $log[p(\Gamma\mid y_{1:T})]$, evaluated at the posterior mode $\hat{\Gamma}$.

Considering $\Gamma_0^{1/2}$ is a lower triangular matrix, and $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are vectors, how do I handle their joint sampling from the multivariate normal distribution?